# javascript array.find() object undefined?

Tags: javascript

Why is the object undefined,
if I call it in arr.find with 'this'?

```
let o = { name: 'foobar' };
let arr = [3, o, 4, 5];

arr.find(x => console.log(this), o);
```

Comment: The lambda is capturing `this` from the current scope, and so your code logs `window` four times.  It works as expected if you convert the lambda to a regular anonymous function.  Your callback doesn't return a truthy value though, so it won't ever find anything.

Comment: What do you expect `this` to refer to? From what you posted it's not clear why exactly it's `undefined`, but it would not be weird for it to be `undefined`.

Comment: arr.find receives a condition and returns the first element that satisfies the condition. What you're doing is "out of the given array, return the first element that - console.log". console.log returns undefined, so the condition returns undefined for all elements and eventually finds nothing.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation @Amy. Im new to JS and did not think of this mechanims.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to use the second parameter of `find()` to set `this` you need to pass a regular function because you can't re-bind `this` to arrow functions:

```js
let o = { name: 'foobar' };
let arr = [3, o, 4, 5];

let p = arr.find(function(x){
         console.log(this)
         return x === this
 }, o);

 console.log("found:", p)
```

Comment: What I'm saying @geoge is that you can't do call `bind(someObj)` on an arrow function to set the value of `this` `find()`'s second param is a value to rebind the function to. Maybe I phrased it poorly.